# Fragment within CollapsingToolbarLayout with ViewPager won't slide down

Tags: android, layout, androiddesignsupport

I have an activity with a CollapsingToolbarLayout and a TabLayout. When I slide right and left it moves perfectly between fragments. However when I try to scroll down (red arrow in the screenshot) it ignores it. I tried adding a ScrollView to the fragment but it did not make a different. Any ideas why?

BTW - Somehow on the second fragment, a RecycleView, the sliding down works. This is seen on the right Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

MainActivity's XML:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="122dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Why have you added two `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: It keeps the TabLayout in place when collapsing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this layout. I have added `TabLayout` in `AppBarLayout`, I believe it should work same as you want. But if you want, you can keep two `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to achieve your desired behaviour. And make sure `fitsSystemWindows` should be same either `true` or `false` in all layouts else you might not see the expected behaviour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="122dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in `Fragment` layout, Use `NestedScrollView` and add `layout_behavior` in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        // Your Layout

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You're the king! If there was a way to offer you a beer I would! Being struggling with that for a long time...

Comment: @Guy Lol. I too had a hard time when did it for the first time. Thanks for the offer any ways!

Comment: you saved my life @Rehan

Comment: you saved my carrier today @Rehan