# Recyclerview not scrolling inside Nested ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

I have `Recyclerview` which is under `Coordinatorlayout` > `NestedScrollview` > `ViewPager` and `ViewPager` has 3 fragment, one has image gallery which is working with the help of `Recyclerview`. Whenever i tried to scroll up or down it doesn't scroll at all. I have already set `photosRecycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` and as soon as i remove this line i am getting scroll working only down side and when i tried to move back up it move up with parent `Nestedscrollview`.

My layout manager is also showing StaggeredGrid as Grid i need to get this kind of layout

[image]

Here is my parent layout for Nestedscrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:colorBackground">


                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:src="@color/custom_transparent_colorBlack"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />



            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/up_NestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabItemes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary_light">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="About" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Media" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Con" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

                android:layout_below="@id/tabItemes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Image Gallery Fragment

```
public class UserPhoto_fragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG="### USER PHOTO ####";
    RecyclerView photosRecycler;
    fetchPhoto_Adapter adapter;
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<String> ImageList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofile_photos,container,false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        photosRecycler=view.findViewById(R.id.userPhotos_recycler);
        layoutManager= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        ImageList=new ArrayList<>();
        SpacesItemDecoration itemDecoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
        photosRecycler.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        photosRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        photosRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        photosRecycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: User Photo Fragment "+getView()+ ImageList.size() );
        if (ImageList.size()==0){
            new fetch_photo().execute();
        }
    }

    public class fetchPhoto_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder>{

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) viewGroup.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofile_photogallery,viewGroup,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(ImageList.get(i)).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(viewHolder.image);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (ImageList!=null && ImageList.size()>0){
                return ImageList.size();
            }else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UserProfile_photoThumb);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Layout file for image gallery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userPhotos_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am facing 2 issue with this code

1. Recyclerview not working in nestedscrollview.
2. StaggeredGridLayoutManager is showing images like GridLayoutManager

Please help me to resolve these issue.Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample project which reproduces the same problems that you are facing

Comment: @SahilManchanda i shared almost complete code.It's a same code  and i am still trying to fix it.

Comment: can we remove the nested scroll view from coordinator layout and put view pager directly ?

Comment: and one thing more, can you make your item 1 and then check if item click listener is working or not. I was facing same problem, i might have a solution then.

Comment: @Abdul i only depends on view pager for scroll events then it kills the purpose of `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 1):

You need [NestedScrollableHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415985/scrolling-behaviour-conflicts-with-a-child-recyclerview-and-a-parent-viewpager2) to scroll in `RecyclerView`

Works for me with following layout tree

`activity.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/vp_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment.xml`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:constraint="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

        <com.anatoli.thebattleofcards.fabric.NestedScrollableHost
            android:id="@+id/rv_items_host"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            constraint:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            constraint:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            constraint:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_items"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"      <!-- change orientation if needs -->
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/layout_padding_small"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/layout_padding_small"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        </com.anatoli.thebattleofcards.fabric.NestedScrollableHost>

        ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put you tabLayout in the appBar:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        .
        .
        .
        />

            <ImageView
                .
                .
                .
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        .
        .
        .
             />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and put nestedScrolling in your fragments. Read this post: [CollapsingToolbar with ViewPager and fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520497/fragment-within-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-viewpager-wont-slide-down)

Comment: It will make tablayout  out from the NestedScrollview

Comment: i also tried your suggestion but it doesn't make any different to `recyclerview`

Comment: please try to make it above layout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your nestedScrollView hasn't covered the entire screen. Try adding this in your nestedScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the adapter try putting this line.

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

Comment: what's the difference between `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` and your solution

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same requirement but have solved it in a different manner,

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Set this attribute to the main content layout in your CoordinatorLayout.

```
    <string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

The layout  looks like

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <ImageView />
                //Header content

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/light_gray">

            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the main fragments parent view must be nested scroll view with `app:layout_behavior`

Note: My fragment contains linear layout, so I just used `wrap_content` if you are using recycler view you should flatten it out inside the fragment

Comment: if i put main content into `NestedScrollView` then it killed the purpose of  `CoordinatorLayou`

Answer (score 0):

1. Since it's viewPager that's directly inside your CoordinatorLayout and not your recyclerView, viewPager shoud have scrolling_layout_behaviour and not your recyclerview

   ```
   <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
      android:layout_below="@id/tabItemes"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
   ```
2. Set up your StaggeredGridLayoutManager like this

   ```
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
   ```

In order for StaggeredGridLayout to work, you must not set your imageView scaletype to cropCenter and height of your cardView containing the imageView element should be set to wrap content and not fixed.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.cardview 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   app:cardcornerradius="4dp" 
   app:cardusecompatpadding="true">

  <linearlayout 
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <imageview
       android:adjustviewbounds="true" 
       android:id="@+id/placePic" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:scaletype="fitXY" />

   </linearlayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.cardview>
```